router static route for wireguard
I am having a little bit of an issue with wireguard. I am not much versed in networking and I am stuck at creating a route such that clients from site A of the network can access clients on site B. let me detail:
On site A (192.168.1.0) I have portainer with some services and one of them is wg-easy docker container. This is accessed through nginx-proxy-manager and a https address with certificates from letsencrypt.
I have setup a number of wireguard clients including my laptop and from my laptop, while I am connected to wireguard I ca access all the clients on Site A straight away after setting up the docker container as detailed by wg-easy here. The only thing I had to do was to comment the SYS_MODULE line to get the container to deploy (I read somewhere that this must be done). So access to site A clients works out of the box so to say from a roaming client (laptop or phone).
I also have a site B (192.168.178.0) where I have a qnap storage and used wireguard to connect to the wg-easy container. Connection is made but I cannot see from site A the qnap on site B. I can see the connection through wireguard is working because traffic comes from qnap (I can see it on its own web interface) and also I can see it in the wg-easy web interface but I cannot ping the wg ip for qnap from the wg-easy container for some reason...
So my question is:
what do I have to do such that from site A I can access clients on site B through the established connection with qnap.
Sorry if this sounds convoluted!
I have an idea to add another wg-easy container on the qnap on site B and see if I can connect it to the wg-easy "server" on site A.
